# Who's responsibility should be to paginate controller/domail service/repository?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My question might seem strange for pros but please take to account that I am coming from ruby on rails world =)

So, I am learning ASP.NET Core. And I like what I am seeing in it compared to rails. But there is always that but... Let me describe the theoretical problem.

Let's say I have a `Product` model. And there are over 9000 records in the database. It is obvious that I have to paginate them. I've read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page) article, but it seems to me that something is wrong here since the controller shouldn't use `context` directly. It has to use some repository (but that example might be provided in such a way only for simplicity).

So my question is: who should be responsible for pagination? Should it be the controller which will receive some queryable object from the repository and take only those records it needs? Or should it be my own business service which does the same? Or should the repository has a method like `public IEnumerable<Product> ListProducts(int offset, int page)`?

Comment: The repository looks a good place certainly if you do not return a queryable list. Maybe you could add page, and pageSize that could be handled by some options on your controller or business service :-)

Comment: It depends on your architecture. If you return `IQuariable<T>` from your repository - you really can do pagination anywhere you want. If not - it's better to keep your pagination as close to your database as you can.

Comment: @teovankot is it a good/acceptable idea to return the `IQueryable<T>` from repository though?

Comment: Absolutely. Linq is meant to simplify your life, not to not use it. Also do realize that as long as your db layer supports linq (in the form of transforming it into SQL and not just linq-to-already-loaded-objects), then LINQ **is** actually a sort of an abstraction layer. The reason that they usually tell not to use context directly is because you want your controller to be independent of the storage mechanism. For example if Microsoft discontinued Entitiy Framework and you would need to use sth else, the scope of refactoring is smaller if the EF-related code is not scattered all over the code

Comment: hmm... seems, it is not a good idea to return `IQueryable<T>` from repository as said [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96070/returning-iqueryablet-from-my-repository-in-repository-pattern-design-pattern) and [here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/192044/should-repositories-return-iqueryable). There are more examples but these are more than enough

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One Domain-Driven-Design solution to this problem is to use a [Specification](http://deviq.com/specification-pattern/). The Specification design pattern describes a query in an object. So you might create a PagedProduct specification which would take in any necessary parameters (pageSize, pageNumber, filter). Then one of your repository methods (usually a List() overload) would accept an ISpecification and would be able to produce the expected result given the specification. There are several benefits to this approach. The specification has a name (as opposed to just a bunch of LINQ) that you can reason about and discuss. It can be unit tested in isolation to ensure correctness. And it can easily be reused if you need the same behavior (say on an MVC View action and a Web API action).

I cover the Specification pattern in the [Pluralsight Design Patterns Library](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/patterns-library).

Comment: thank you for your response. I've watched the video you provided. I've read about specification already before that. But even in the video you say that this pattern is used for filtering the data and you can't just use the paging specification like other specifications are used (it won't be passed to `Where` method). And it will require to pass common specifications and paging specifications seprately

Comment: It's up to how you implement it. You can certainly include paging/sorting in the specification as long as you write your repository in a way that it can use this information in constructing its query.

Comment: Also, I've got paging in my Specification nuget package now: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ardalis.Specification/

Answer (score 1):

For first, I would like to remind you that all such examples you linked are overly simplified, so it shouldn't drive you to believe that that is the correct way. Simple things, with fewer abstraction layers are easier to oversee and understand (at least in the case of simple examples for beginners when the reader may not know where to look for what) and that's why they are presented like that.

Regarding the question: I would say none of the above. If I had to decide between them then I would say the service and/or the repository, but that depends on how you define your storage layer, etc.

"None of the above", then what? My preference is to implement an intermediary layer between the service layer and the Web UI layer. The service layer exposes manipulation functionality but for read operations, exposes the whole collection as an *IQueryable*, and **not** as an *IEnumerable*, so that you can utilize LINQ-to-whatever-storage.

Why am I doing this, many may ask. Because almost all the time you will use specialized viewmodels. To display the list of products on an admin page, for example, you would need to display values of columns in the products table, but you are very likely to need to display its category as well. Very rarely is it the case that you need data only from one table and by exposing the items as an `IQueryable<T>` you get the benefit of being able to do `Select`s like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductAdminTableViewModel> GetProducts(int page, int pageSize)
{
    backingQueryable.Select(prod => new ProductAdminTableViewModel
    {
        Id = prod.Id,
        Category = prod.Category.Name, // your provider will likely resolve this to a Join
        Name = prod.Name
    }).Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
}
```

As commented, by using the backing store as an `IQueryable` you will be able to do projections before your query hits the DB and thus you can avoid any nasty Select N+1s.

The reason that this sits in an intermediary layer is simply you do not want to add references to your web project neither in your repo nor in your service layer (project) but because of this you cannot implement the viewmodel-specific queries in your service layer simply because the viewmodels cannot be resolved there. This implies that the viewmodels reside in this same project as well, and to this end, the MVC project only contains views, controllers and the ASP.NET MVC-related guttings of your app. I usually call this intermediate layer as 'SolutionName.Web.Core' and it references the service layer to be able to access the `IQueryable<T>`-returning method.